# How Can I implement JWT grant authentication without login to docusign from browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I want to implement DocuSign JWT grant authentication. I went through examples provided by DocuSign and I am able to run the application perfectly. But I need to implement DocuSign in my application which is of providing Restful APIs using Spring boot and DocuSign login should happen without explicit login. In the given example, it will ask for explicit login as shown in the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn4TP.png)

What setting do I need to change in the example or any sample example where I can give account details inside the code so that it will be authenticated automatically and using JWT grant it generates an access token. Using FeignClient can I call this API `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=YOUR_RESPONSE_TYPE&scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES&client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY&state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing over here is to login to be able to provide user consent, which can be done through any of the following ways mentioned over [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/)

**Update:**

Replying to the comment regarding an example, not sure if you are using the SDK or directly calling the API but here goes both:

1- If you are using the SDK, you should be able to go through the authentication process of the JWT using this [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/java/auth/).

2- If you are calling the API directly, you can follow this [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/). Start with step number 2 if you already have the consent.

Comment: Can we make an example application to use the JWT grant by default instead of asking for the type of authentication?